# Get a list outside a loop

Tags: java

I need to get a list from another list so here is what I have done :

```
ArrayList<String> userList = user.getListSalarieByManager(login);
ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList;
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    demandesList = d.getDemandesForManager(userList.get(i));
}
```

Then I need to get the data from the list `demandesList` but I can't get this list outside the loop because *this not have been initialized*.

How can I get the data from the list inside the loop ?

Comment: Why are you initilaizing the users on the next line? That doesn't make any sense..it adds extra, unneeded, lines and makes the code slightly harder to read.

Comment: @NathanHughes But my function getDemandesForManager() return a list, how can I add a list to a list ? I've found `addAll`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you haven't actually initialized your second list.

```
ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList;
```

Should be:

```
ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList = new ArrayList<DHDemande>();
```

By the way, the way your loop is set up sets the entire `demandesList` every iteration. Are you perhaps looking for [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E))?

Edit: to answer you question in the comments:

Yes, you can add a list to another list using [`ArrayList#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) - that would look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> userList = user.getListSalarieByManager(login);
ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList = new ArrayList<DHDemande>();
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    demandesList.addAll(d.getDemandesForManager(userList.get(i)));
}
```

Edit 2: just a small note, you can replace your for loop with a for-each, since you don't really need to know the value of `i` (index).

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    demandesList.addAll(d.getDemandesForManager(userList.get(i)));
}
```

Turns into:

```
for (String user : userList) {
    demandesList.addAll(d.getDemandesForManager(user));
}
```

Comment: Well thanks you, it works I thought `ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList;` was enough. Yes, that's what I was looking for. But my function `getDemandesForManager()` return a list, can I add a list to a list ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible using `addAll`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection) - I have updated the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to initialize the list properly, inside or outside the loop,
but it appears that you want to add elements to the list inside the loop.
I changed your iteration over the loop to the modern java list iteration style.

```
// initialize variables just so this example compiles
UserProvider user = new UserProvider(); 
Object login = null; 
DHDemandeProvider d = new DHDemandeProvider();  only

ArrayList<String> userList;
userList = user.getListSalarieByManager(login);
ArrayList<DHDemande> demandesList = new ArrayList<DHDemande>(); // construct list
for (String u: userList) {
    demandesList.add(d.getDemandesForManager(u));  // add elements to list
}
```